Для чего тестировщики смотрят cookie в DevTools?
Часто слышу то что тестировщики должны работать с куками в DevTools например(Например распарсить токен)
Не совсем понимаю для чего и как тестировщик может распарсить токен
Тут скорее два вопроса:
1-Для чего чаще всего тестировщики смотрять куки
2-Как распарсить токен

Иногда нужно проверять срок жизни куки, если он ограничен по постановке задачи. Так же может потребоваться удалить их, чтобы проверить как ведет себя приложение если кука протухла, а какие-то фоновые запросы требующие авторизацию продолжают выполняться.
